# Image control uses transformation differently than other controls?

Tags: wpf, xaml, transform

Scratching my head. Why in the world do these controls appear at different locations? Here's my XAML:

- First (black) rectangle is the reference rectangle.
- Second (red) rectangle appears correctly centered on top of the reference rect.
- The image control (gray) while having the same size and transform, appears slightly drifted.

  ```
  <Canvas Width="800" Height="500">
    <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Canvas.Left="300" Canvas.Top="200" Stroke="Black" />

    <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Canvas.Left="300" Canvas.Top="200" Stroke="Red">
      <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="30" CenterX="50" CenterY="50" />
      </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    </Rectangle>

    <Image Width="100" Height="100" Canvas.Left="300" Canvas.Top="200">
      <Image.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="30" CenterX="50" CenterY="50" />
      </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
  </Canvas>
  ```

Appears like this in WPF designer:

[image]

Comment: Of course it is a square. The Width and Height is mentioned in the code above. As noted by Jake in his answer below, this appears to be a difference of `RenderTransformOrigin` between `Rectangle` and `Image` controls.

Comment: This is just the flawed designer. Set the Source property of the Image (and probably also Stretch=Fill) and the problem is gone. The default value of the RenderTransformOrigin property is (0,0) for all UIElements.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned,the shape classed (like Rectangle) and Image may have diffrent behaviors for renderorigin,if you edit both values of Image rotatetransform centerX/Y to 0,they may behave the same

```
<Canvas Width="800" Height="500">
<Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Canvas.Left="300" Canvas.Top="200     Stroke="Black" />
<Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Canvas.Left="300" Canvas.Top="200"    Stroke="Red">
   <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
     <RotateTransform Angle="30" CenterX="50" CenterY="50" />
   </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
```

```
 <Image Width="100" Height="100" Canvas.Left="300" Canvas.Top="200">
   <Image.RenderTransform>
     <RotateTransform Angle="30" CenterX="0" CenterY="0" />
   </Image.RenderTransform>
 </Image>
```

Comment: Yep. This appears to be the case. Setting `RenderTransformOrigin` on both controls makes the transform correct.